# CSS - how wide, is too wide? Will a width of 20000px cause problems for any web browsers / devices?

Tags: html, css

I want to build a horizontal carousel. No images, just simple text. I want 27 items in the carousel. And I'm thinking of just drawing them all in. I want to be able to scroll (gracefully) from item 1, to item 27, or between any other 2 items in the carousel.

I've done this kind of thing before by adding items dynamically, but that's a big pain (and in that case I didn't know how big the carousel might be, and I was working with images).

So I'm looking at something like -

```
<ul id="carousel" class="my-carousel" style="transform: translateX(-1000px)">
  <li class="item" style="width: 500px;">
    <h5>item 1</h5>
  </li>
  <li class="item" style="width: 500px;">
    <h5>item 2</h5>
  </li>
  <li class="item" style="width: 500px;">
    <h5>item 3</h5>
  </li>
  ...
  <li class="item" style="width: 500px;">
    <h5>item 27</h5>
  </li>
</ul>

ul.my-carousel {
  list-style: 'none';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}
ul.my-carousel li.item {
  display: inline-block;  // or flex maybe
}
```

I'd be setting the width's dynamically, and then moving smoothly from item to item by adjusting that `translateX` attribute on the `ul` element. So to get to the 10th element

```
document.getElementById('carousel').style.translateX = '-5000px';
```

Is this a bad idea? Am I likely to put a strain on some devices / browsers? Will they make a mess of it if I go that wide?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont wrap it by a element with **overflow:hidden**, you will observe a scrollbar to the right of your page...

So you need to wrap it, then I think there is no limitation for how long it can be.. But remember if you load 27 images at once it will take some time to load your page...

Why you are building your own carousel? Why dont you use something allready made and tested? like https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ or atleast take it as inspiration.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need much functionality so it's almost as quick to build it myself as it to configure someone else's code. Also I want my page to load quickly. (And lastly the code you recommended uses jQuery, and I'm working with react.js so I definitely don't want to bundle an additional DOM manipulation library).

Comment: @AidanEwen ok well then if you wrap your UL with div that has overflow:hidden and  width: 100% you are fine :)